# WCF Service Doesn't Maintain State Between Client Calls

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I am connecting to a web service, where first method initializes search and then another one gets result. I am able to connect to it and initialize the search, but when I call the update method, I don't get any result. It seems like the service cannot recognize, that I am the same person who initialized the search. Any idea how to get this working?
P.S: Other methods, that don"t need initialization work great.
Simplified code looks like:

```
Service service = new Service();
service.StartSearch(param1, param2);
string result = service.UpdateResults();
```

Results updating method has no parameters.

Comment: Web services don't usually maintain state between calls - is this one of your own services?

Comment: I think you need to show the code for StartSearch and UpdateResults

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. When I was working on this same problem with PHP, I had to create my own class and instance of this class send instead of parameters to the StartSearch method as weel as the UpdateResults method, even though there are no parameters this somehow worked. But in visual studio I cannot do something like that.

Comment: Steve, I don't have access to source code of those methods.

Comment: @Dice, the only returned value from StartSearch is in every case int 0, so I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: BTW, I tried to get the data with HttpPost by using WebRequest, and I get the same results. But when I try it in the browser, everything works.

Comment: If that is the full extent of your service calling code it would be worth posting your client binding configuration from your app.config or web.config file also.

Comment: I'm still under impression that you are served a cookie and you ignore it (instead of sending it back). Did you actually try the code I provided in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all guesswork of course, but maybe your service's `StartSearch()` method assigns something like a session cookie to you? In this case you need your cookie container to exist, and it doesn't exist by default.

Here's the code I would try:

```
Service service = new Service();
service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // initialize cookie container
service.StartSearch(param1, param2);
string result = service.UpdateResults();
```

Comment: Finally, I solved it, the problem was in binding code generated by VS. The property allowCookies was set to false, as soon as I changed it to true, I got my results. 
Zruty, I think I can mark your answer as correct, because your idea about cookieContainer pointed me to the right direction.